# Italic font changes TextView layout in Galaxy S5

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a very strange behavior of TextView layout which only happens in Galaxy S5. 
The problem is that when I set the text style to italic, the TextView that aligned with the screen right side seems to get out form the screen (the TextView has a rectangle border).

This strange problem appears only in Galaxy S5! in all other devices that I tried my application and even on other Samsung like S3 and S4 everything looks just fine!

Can anyone explain this behavior and maybe can offer some solutions to this ?

I do have screenshots but I still can't publish images here.

Please refer to layout xml as is! I just comment the textStyle="italic" and then everything looks great!
Only on S5 guys..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/Black" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/timerLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/nicetextframe" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imRecording"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_recording"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTimer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/gpsDataTable"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="@drawable/nicetextframe"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:textColor="@color/YellowGreen"
        android:textSize="35sp" 
        android:textStyle="italic" /> 
         Ï         
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/guegesLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/timerLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSpeed"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/gpsDataTable"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/nicetextframe"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0.0"
        android:textColor="@color/YellowGreen"
        android:textSize="40sp" 
        android:textStyle="italic"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDistance"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/gpsDataTable"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/nicetextframe"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0.0"
        android:textColor="@color/YellowGreen"
        android:textSize="40sp" 
        android:textStyle="italic" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/guegesLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/nicesqureframe"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/black_gradient" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/btStartStop"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:textColor="@color/DarkGreen"
        android:textOff="@string/NewTrip"
        android:textOn="@string/StopTrip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btClose"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:text="@string/Close"
        android:textColor="@color/DarkGreen"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You could just link the images through one link (since you can't post more) through something such as an imgur album

Comment: can you see this image?
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_u6KEV21eGGWllsZzlTb0NsWUk/edit

Comment: I cannot, you can use a site such as [Imgur](http://imgur.com/) to upload images without an account.

Comment: bad layout:
http://i.imgur.com/0Myd4hj.png
good layout:
http://i.imgur.com/v8rLNPo.png

Can you see this now ?

Comment: Please post your layout file.  Also, do you have multiple versions of this layout file defined?

Comment: I've just added the XML layout so you can see.